# How to set mesh to the particles? (Not converting)

Tags: mesh, modifiers, particles, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to make basic explosion. I used quick explode effect and then done some stuff with particles settings etc. to make it better but I can't figure out how to set the right mesh collision to my particles. I can see they land on the plane as halo particles (as you can see it on screenshot) not as mesh gained from explode modifier. I was searching quite long everywhere and didnt find any solution. They don't collide aswell but that's clear since rigidbody world sees them only as particles, not mesh. (They also don't rotate - also clear) To summ up I just want to make them fall and land like a real pieces of the icosphere. Thanks in advance! PS. I don't want to use Cell Fracture.

[image: particles dont collide as mesh but with halo]

[image: particles dont collide as mesh]

[image: particles dont collide with each other]

[image: active modifiers to the model]

Comment: I haven't time to answer everything here and am talking vers 2.77, but it should be similar in 2.8+. To collide with the ground - In the ground plane's physics, tick the 'collision' button.
In the particle settings (ICO sphere) ensure the 'Died' box is set in the "Render" tab. In it's modifier settings (Explode Modifier) make sure you have ticked the "Dead' box also.
You can stop them bouncing around by selecting the Ground plane and ticking the "Kill" box in it's physics properties.  This tick can be keyframed at any frame.  Ensure it's also keyframed to off (unticked) at frame 1.